# Density of continuous knots in the plane transversal to some circles

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

This is an exercise from the book "Knots and Links" by Rolfsen (exercise 6 in section 2C)

Let $\kappa : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$ be a continuous imbedding.  Let $M := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2-(0,0) : |x| \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.   Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Show that there exists an imbedding $\lambda : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2-(0,0) $ satisfying

1. $|\kappa - \lambda | < \epsilon$
2. $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ are homotopic in $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$
3. $\lambda$ anx $\kappa$ have disjoint images
4. $\lambda$ is transversal to $M$
5. The image of $\lambda$ meets $M$ in only finitely many points.

   Here transversality means that each point of intersection has a neighborhood homeomorphic to the plane such that one set (really its intersection with the neighborhood) is mapped to the x axis and the other to the y axis.

Of course in the smooth setting one has tubular neighborhoods and the density of transversal maps to work with.  In the purely topological setting I'm completely lost.   Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I don't think this can be true for all $\epsilon > 0$.  Do you want to say "for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$"?

Comment: It doesn't even seem true for smooth embeddings without that condition.

Comment: @daswerth : Thanks for your feedback.  Why don't you think it can be true for all positive $\epsilon$ and why isn't it true in the smooth setting?

Comment: @daswerth The number $\epsilon$ appears only in condition 1. The smaller $\epsilon $ is, the more restrictive condition 1 becomes.

Comment: That's right.  I misread the condition.  I believe the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get $\lambda$ is to use complex analysis. Let $f$ be a conformal map of the unit disk $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ onto the domain $\Omega$ bounded by $\kappa(S^1)$. Let   $K=\{w\in\Omega: \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial\Omega)\ge \epsilon /2 \}$. The preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ is a compact subset of $D$. Therefore, it is contained in $|z|<r$ for some $r<1$. The embedding $\lambda$ obtained by restricting  $f$ to $|z|=r$ satisfies 1 and 3 (for 1, one has to use [Caratheodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mapping%29) which makes $|f(re^{it})-f(e^{it})|$ uniformly small). It automatically satisfies 2 (by straight-line homotopy) if you make $\epsilon$ smaller than the distance from $\kappa$ to the origin $(0,0)$. Now you are in the smooth setting where you can work toward 4 and 5.

An alternative approach is to use a smooth distance-type function, that is, a positive smooth function $\rho$ defined in $\Omega$  such that $\rho(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\partial \Omega$. Such a function can be constructed without Riemann mapping theorem, by using the [Whitney decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_covering_lemma) of $\Omega$. See, e.g., *Singular integrals* by Stein. Almost every level set of $\rho $ is a disjoint union of smooth $1$-manifolds (closed curves). For sufficiently small $\delta$ the set $\rho=\delta$ separates $\partial\Omega$  from the origin; therefore one of its components does the same. This component provides an approximating curve $\lambda$, but unfortunately the task of finding its parametrization that satisfies 1 remains somewhat nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks! I've just started reading. Do you mean $dist (w, im \kappa ) \geq \epsilon / 2$ in the second line?

Comment: Yep, I think the first paragraph does it.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, I inserted the  $\partial$ symbol that was missing in the second line.

Comment: Actually I'm slightly worried about the parametrizations being *pointwise* close.  I probably should have been clearer that that's what I meant in condition 1

Comment: Or maybe you meant last line in the second paragraph to apply to the proof in the first paragraph as well

Comment: What about maybe redefining $K$ to be the set of points that are $\epsilon / 2$ away from the point on the image of $\kappa$ to which they radially project in the coordinates of the Riemann mapping?  That might be complete nonsense

Comment: @Timkinsella Parametrizations being $C^0$-close follows from the fact that $f$ is continuous on the closed disk: I added this to the  post. Formally, let $\tilde \kappa$ be the restriction of $f$ to $|z|=1$, and let $\lambda$ be restriction of $f(rz)$ to $|z|=1$ composed with $\tilde \kappa^{-1}\circ\kappa$.